# UI5-Application: Call to functionimport works ONLY in WebIDE but fails everywhere else

Tags: odata, sapui5, http-status-code-500, sap-web-ide, sap-gateway

We are developing a custom UI5 application.
It is developed in the WebIDE, and therefore deployed as a BSP.
When we use the underlying model for calls ( currently 3, no CRUD ), we chose the path of using ONLY functionimports to communicate with the backend.
All of them work with the POST method.
And all of them work ONLY inside the WebIDE.

Once, I access the BSP URL otherwise, we get HTTP 500 error with "error while requesting  the ressource.

We already created links, to enable special portfowarding, no result.
Let's stick to my URL from the BSP first.

I paste it into my 3 browsers: 500.
We also created a special non dialogue-user with proper roles and permissions, and in the SICF tree we assigned it .
Again, when calling from inside the WebIDE, the functionimport-calls work, otherwise not.
Error-Logs are empty.
Dumps do not happen.
ST05 trace shows where 500 is passed, deeply inside the HTTP framework, yet no chance to spot the code location, neither a breaktpoint.
In SICF logon-settings we have:

- Types all, also flagged "all", SAML: inherited from parent node, sec-sessions Not limited, fix user and pw, sec: Standard, auth:Standard Sap user.
  The gui-options contain ONLY one flag: ~CHECK_CSRF_TOKEN 0.

In my client I use :

[image]

Where the model is initialized as :

```
function initModelV2()  {

var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_this_is_a_company_secret_service/";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sUrl);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

}

What else can I do to get "at least closer" to the reason, WHY ?

Comment: Why are the function imports POST?

Comment: Why not ? I query some informations in the first 2 and the third issues a real "posting" to the db.

Comment: GET usually means that you pass data via URL parameter. POST means you pass data in the request body. It has literally nothing to do if you read or write data in your backend.

Comment: You recommend me to change it and try again ?

Comment: Changed it, regenerated it. SAME result. WebIDE: OK, else not.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it, and believe it or not, sometimes simple logic helps.
I debugged the backend of CL_HTTP_RESPONSE, and once I saw, GET_STATUS, I thought to look for SET_STATUS.
There it was:

```
this.rModel.setHeaders( {"X-Requested-With" : "X" } );
```

Was missing.

Though I set it in the manifest of my model, it was not passed.
Once set in the code, it worked.

I wonder, why it is not accepted in manifest.

I have an assumption.

1st: I have this in my manifest ( yellow arrow shows, where i HAD it set up before):

[image]

But I also have an instantiation in my code, in servicebindings.js with this code

[image]

Can it be, that, in the end, I have accidently created 2 models ?

Comment: Doing it through the manifest is the recommended way, yes. Making another unnamed model overwrites it

Comment: Wonder which way is the best practice to get the model in onInit. Because one cannot get it, EXCEPT, if we use the call to ownercomponent.

Comment: You mean `getOwnerComponent().getModel()`? Might work with `getView().getModel()` as well, they should propagate. Do it after the call to the prototype's `onInit` method though.

Comment: That's what I meant. I WANT it to be obtained in "onInit". I do not want to bother with that during any moment later on .